# AlarmManager with BroadCastReceiver: Programed two alarms but received only one

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have two alarms and a broadcastreceiver:

```
AlarmManager am2=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MyReceiverAlarm.class);
intent2.putExtra("name", "juan");
PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent2, 0);

am2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+1000, pi2);



AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiverAlarm.class);
intent.putExtra("name", "jose");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+8000, pi);
```

However, I'm always receiving the first one, only. I  always get "juan" and the alarm is fires after 8 seconds. 
I don't understand the reason...If i have two alarms why fires one ?

My BroadcastReceiver:

```
Toast.makeText(context, extras.getString("nombre") + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
String name=extras.getString("nombre");
if (extras != null && name.equals("juan") {
    String callForwardString =  PHONE ;
                Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

    Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", callForwardString, "#");
    intentCallForward.setData(uri2);
    intentCallForward.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(intentCallForward);
} else {
    ...
}
```

Is not possible to program two alarms?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the request code (second parameter passed to `getBroadcast()`:

```
PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, intent2, 0);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, 0);
```